# Will Blazor allow a Selenium WebDriver to be created

Tags: selenium, blazor

In a Blazor app is it possible to create a Selenium WebDriver (Chrome, Firefox in essence another browser). Thus enabling Blazor to perform scraping. I think I know the answer to his but I just want to be sure.

If it is not possible is there another clever way to get the HTML from a web site in a Blazor app?

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Yes. If canvasses are used without overlayed DOM elements, things might get a little tricky, though. The web assembly bits are usually used in the same way javascript would be used when it comes to manipulating the DOM. The benefit of web assembly comes when generating graphics... (think charts and graphs, or video games) It's slower than direct javascript at manipulating the DOM (because it also uses javascript as a bridge between wasm and dom), but faster when generating/updating graphics (canvas).  There is still a DOM here so Selenium calls are the same.  Be sure to use webdriverwaits.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in Server-side Blazor.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0la2EbX8Ow

No, in Client-side Blazor (WASM). Although, I haven't explored enough of the options using JavaScript.